# How do I specify binary data in a COM RGS file

Tags: com, registration, registry, rgs

I'm adding some custom data data to the registry during the registration of a COM object by adding it to the rgs file.

Adding a DWORD value (specified by = d '3' below) gets entered into the registry as expected.

For the binary/hex data however it does not get entered into the registry correctly.
Can anyone advise what the correct syntax is for entering binary data in a rgs file?

```
HKLM
{
   NoRemove SOFTWARE
   {
      NoRemove MyCompany
      {
         NoRemove Settings
         {
            val 'MyTestDword' = d '3'
            val 'MyTestBinaryData' = b '00 01 04'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax was not to use spaces between the hex values

```
val 'MyTestBinaryData' = b '000104'
```